# Proper normal subgroup of a direct product

Tags: group-theory

The following is part of a proof of Proposition 5.5 appearing in [here](http://ac.els-cdn.com/S002186930800611X/1-s2.0-S002186930800611X-main.pdf?_tid=3f07f3f4-4304-11e7-a026-00000aacb361&acdnat=1495907297_40f9d611d3b13bcfceaccb912ff7f73b). I have provided the relevant details below.

Let $G = A \times B$ be a non-abelian group. Suppose that $A \cong B$ and let $\phi$ denote the isomorphism between $A$ and $B$. Further assume that $H = \{ (a, \phi(a) \,|\, a\in A \}$. It is clear that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$. Since $G$ is non-abelian, there exists a maximal normal subgroup of $A$ such that $Z(A) \leq M$. Consider $A = \bigcup \limits_{t \in T}tM$ where $T$ is a left transversal of $M$ in $A$.

> I need to prove that $K := \{(t, \phi(t) \,|\, t\in T\} (M \times \phi(M))$ is proper normal subgroup of $G$.

Since $G = A \times \phi(A)$, it follows that $M \times \phi(M)$ is a proper normal subgroup of $G$. I'm not sure how $K$ is a subgroup of $G$ in the first place?

Comment: This isn't true in general, so you might have left something out. If $A$ is a nonabelian simple group, then $M$ is trivial and $H =K$, which is not a normal subgroup. But $K = H(M \times \phi(M))$ is always a subgroup.

Comment: If $G$ is solvable would this change anything?

Comment: Yes, in that case $A/M$ is abelian, and so $G/(M \times \phi(M))$ is abelian, and hence all subgroups of $G$ that contain $M \times \phi(M)$ are normal.

Comment: @DerekHolt, sorry for the late reply as I was ill for an extended period of time. I'm finding it difficult to understand the part of $K$ given by $\{ (t, \phi(t)) \,| \, t\in T\} $where $T$ is a transversal of $M$ in $A$. Is this a subgroup of $G$? I'm not sure how $K$ is a subgroup of $G$ initially.

Comment: Try and prove that $K = H(M \times \phi(M))$, which proves that $K$ is a subgroup. LHS $\subseteq$ RHS is clear, so to prove equality, you just need to prove that $H \subseteq K$. To prove that, note that every $a \in A$ can be written as $tm$ with $t \in T$ and $m \in M$.